# std::transform applied to data member of sequence's element

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

Please help me to find a *more* elegant way to rewrite this snippet using `std::transform` or similar algorithm:

```
for (auto& warning : warnings)
{
    NormalizePath(warning.path, GetParsedPathLength(warning.path), longestPathLength);
};
```

Where `warning` is a `struct`.

This is what I came up with:

```
std::transform(begin(warnings), end(warnings), begin(warnings),
    [longestPathLength](auto& warning)
    {
        NormalizePath(warning.path, GetParsedPathLength(warning.path), longestPathLength);
        return warning;
    });
```

But it requires a copy of full data-structure. Is there a way to create a modifiable view of a original sequence that contains only `path` member? So transform could be rewritten only accepting and returning modified `path`. And in the end all the changes should affect original `warnings` sequence.

Comment: "elegant" is mostly a matter of opinion. The original version of the code looks cromulently elegant to me.

Comment: I mean, you could wrap ranged-for into for_each algorithm, but why would you do so? Original code is clear and concise enough as it is.

Comment: "requires a copy of full data-structure" - how so? You are passing by reference.

Comment: @Nelfeal it's a bit misleading. Predicate returns by value. So there will be at least one copy: from predicate to the original element.

Comment: copy can be avoided : just change :

`[longestPathLength](auto& warning) -> auto &`

Comment: @SoupEndless Fair enough, but I think you're confused. You don't need to return anything in that lambda if you take `warning` by reference. And so you don't need `std::transform` but rather `std::for_each`. However, that would just be a more complicated way to write your original for loop.

Comment: @Nelfeal I was confused indeed, I read predicate signature as `Ret fun(const Type &a);` from [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and automatically thought it must be value type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ranges (C++20), you might *"shorter"* first version to:

```
for (auto& path : warnings | std::views::transform(&Warning::path))
{
    NormalizePath(path, GetParsedPathLength(path), longestPathLength);
}
```

Comment: That's beatiful.

Comment: Can you please share sources you've learnt this? I wasn't able to see such usage of  `views::transform` anywhere.

Comment: `std::function` can able to do that syntax, [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) allow to use it more widely.

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially create some temporary function through lambdas and function bindings:

```cpp
auto func = [](int size, auto& str){ 
    NormalizePath(str, GetParsedPathLength(str), size); 
};
```

Then call the function with `ranges::for_each`:

```cpp
std::ranges::for_each(
    warnings, std::bind_front(func, longestPathLength), &warning::path
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/13Y73EMMj)